# NHibernate adding to child set leads to query with large/excessive number of rows returned

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a problem, that when i add an object to a child collection that is a set, NHibernate does a select over all child objects in the collection. This leads to the "Large number of rows returned" alert in NHProf and finally, if there are enough objects in the collection to a System.OutOfMemoryException.

Edit: NHibernate Version was 3.0.0 Beta 2

Edit 2: Solved this by making the OrderPositions collection a bag. Still would be interested on how to avoid such an expensive query if a set is needed.

Edit 3: Thought about it a little more. Since equality and getHash are implemented in the c# class, there is probably no way for NH to determine if it can add an item to a set other then populating the whole set and trying to actually add the item to it. Still being able to tell NH how it can determine equality in the hbm file, by say a natural-id constraint would be great. Is this possible?

Here is the query that NHibernate produces when i call
    someOrder.AddOrderPosition(someOrderPosition);

```
SELECT orderposit0_.OrderId              as OrderId1_,
       orderposit0_.OrderPositionId      as OrderPos1_1_,
       orderposit0_.OrderPositionId      as OrderPos1_4_0_,
       orderposit0_.OrderedAmount        as OrderedA3_4_0_,
       orderposit0_.OrderId              as OrderId4_0_,
       orderposit0_.ArticleId            as ArticleId4_0_
FROM   OrderPositions orderposit0_
WHERE  orderposit0_.OrderId = 3889 /* @p0 */
```

Here is the sample code:

```
public class Order : Entity<int>
{
    private ISet<OrderPosition> orderPositions = new HashedSet<OrderPosition>();

    public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<OrderPosition> OrderPositions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.orderPositions;
        }

        protected set
        {
            this.orderPositions = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual void AddOrderPosition(OrderPosition orderPosition)
    {
        if (orderPosition.Order != null)
        {
            orderPosition.Order.OrderPositions.Remove(orderPosition);
        }

        orderPosition.Order = this;
        this.OrderPositions.Add(orderPosition);
    }
}


public class OrderPosition : Entity<int>
{
    public virtual int OrderedAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}


<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="DataTransfer" namespace="DataTransfer">
  <class name="Order" table="Orders">
    <id name="Id" column="OrderId">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <set name="OrderPositions" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="OrderId" />
      <one-to-many class="OrderPosition" />
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"  assembly="DataTransfer" namespace="DataTransfer">
  <class name="OrderPosition" table="OrderPositions">
    <id name="Id" column="OrderPositionId">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="OrderedAmount" />
    <many-to-one name="Order" column="OrderId" cascade="all" />
    <many-to-one name="Article" column="ArticleId" cascade="all" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the semantics of set and bag. A bag is an unordered collection of items, which might contain duplicates. A set is an unordered collection of items with no duplicates. Hence NHibernate has to perform a select on the set-based child collection to ensure that no duplicates exist before saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding unsaved-value to your `<id>` element on your OrderPositions mapping.  For example:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"  assembly="DataTransfer" namespace="DataTransfer">
  <class name="OrderPosition" table="OrderPositions">
    <id name="Id" column="OrderPositionId" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="OrderedAmount"
    <many-to-one name="Order" column="OrderId" cascade="all" />
    <many-to-one name="Article" column="ArticleId" cascade="all" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I haven't had a chance to test this, but I'm assuming since there's no way to tell if an entity has been previously saved it is checking to see if it already exists.  unsaved-value allows NHibernate to know that the object has not been saved previously.

Comment: Adding an unsaved-value didn't make a difference. But you got me thinking. Equality in the Entity base class just looks at the id, plus there are no further constraints in the db (and in the domain). So using set semantics makes no sense. Using a bag is the right choice here. No unbound query that way also.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it worked out.  Wasn't entirely sure if my idea would work, but I am happy to hear that it helped lead to the actual solution.

Comment: Thanks, you know how it is, talking about it often helps. Still i wonder how NHibernate would do it if i really needed a set, setting a natural-id around the two many-to-one associations didn't change a thing. I would expect NH to then make the where clause like "WHERE OrderId = someOrderId && ArticleId = someArticleId", but it didn't.

Comment: NHibernate defaults the unsaved-value to default(T), which for integer PKs is zero (0). That's why it didn't make a difference.